cmake compilation error macOS: Could NOT find OpenMP_C
I have been having trouble with compiling several totally unrelated programs using cmake on my MacBook Pro M1 Max, but I keep getting the same error. After typing in cmake -B build (plus the program's respective options), a small number of processes begin, but eventually I get an error saying:
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:581 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/_deps/mctc-lib-src/CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have been having this problem for weeks now, with at least three different programs. I found multiple posts where people have similar (possibly identical) problems (this post in particular sounds very similar), but I have not yet found a solution that has worked.
From everything I have read, it sounds like cmake is trying to use Xcode's version of Clang, but this doesn't support MPI, and I need to direct cmake to the system's (or, in my case, MacPort's) installation of Clang.
So far, I have tried to do this by setting the environment variables prior to the cmake command:
export CC=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/bin/clang
export CXX=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/bin/clang++
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/include"

I have also tried to include it in the cmake command itself:
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCC=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/bin/clang -DCXX=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/bin/clang++ -DLDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/lib -DCPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-19/include

I have also tried to use different paths, in case I am directing cmake to the wrong files, including CC=/opt/local/bin/aarch64-apple-darwin24-gcc-14.2.0, but I have still not found anything that works.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Am I making any obvious mistakes? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This question is similar to: OpenMP on macOS Mojave. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RichardBarber This question is completely different to the other one (which is why it never popped up in any of my searches), but the answer is the same. If you write a similar answer to this question, I will accept it—it does no use closing this question if the answer cannot be found if you search for an error message.

The error statesmissing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES, but you never address that error.

@RichardBarber I thought setting LDFLAGS was addressing the error. If you take a look at the other post I linked, you'll see that their advice was to set those variables and that it worked for that person. If you search for the error itself, the only answers that pop up are for setting the variables I listed in my question. So, like I said, if give an answer here similar to the answer you gave in the post you linked, I will accept it. If not, I will answer it myself, but I believe you deserve the credit.

It turns out the answer was not specify a path for the different variables, as was suggested in the posts I had found during my search. The answer (as mentioned in this post linked by @RichardBarber) was simply to specify the compiler's name in the command:
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCC="clang" -DCXX="clang++" -DOpenMP_C_FLAGS=-fopenmp=lomp -DOpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES="libomp"

There was no need to assign the paths to any binaries or libraries.
